# following pods are integrated into targets that do not have the same Swift version

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, cocoapods

I am updating my project to Swift 3. When updating some of my cocoapods to swift 3, I receive the following message in terminal, after running pod install:

```
 Analyzing dependencies
[!] The following pods are integrated into targets that do not have the same Swift version:

- AWSCore required by myApp (Swift 3.0.1), myApptests (Swift 3.0)
- AWSS3 required by myApp (Swift 3.0.1), myApptests (Swift 3.0)
- Alamofire required by myApp (Swift 3.0.1), myApptests (Swift 3.0)
```

There is a lengthy thread here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5864 about the issue, and I tried the proposed solution, but when I run pod install, i still get the same message.

Here is my pod file:

[image]

outside the one given link i haven't found much on this issue. Anyone else experienced the same problem? Any solutions? I just installed Xcode 8.1 and Swift 3.0.1 last weekend.

Answer (score 41):

I just solved a recent issue when I updated my swift3 project to swift4 one with Xcode9, the problem said: 
`[!] The following pods are integrated into targets that do not have the same Swift version:`

`Appsee required by MyApp (Swift 4.0), MyAppUnitTest (Swift 3.0)`
...Allpods

My solution was: 
With my main target `MyApp` with the swift version at 4.0, I also updated my UnitTest version to 4.0 into `Build Settings` --> `Swift Language Version`

Comment: Worked for me too :)

Comment: Thank you, it was fault of tests language version.

Answer (score 6):

This problem gets worse with `Xcode 9` since it supports both 3.2 and 4.0 swift versions, but Cocoa Pods doesn't support this yet:

```
[!] The following pods are integrated into targets that do not have the same Swift version:
- XCGLogger required by target1 (Swift 4.0), target2 (Swift 3.0)
```

Workaround: switch target1 to swift 3.2 temporarily, install cocoa pods, then switch it back to swift 4.0.

Comment: do you have a source for CocoaPods not supporting this yet? or this is an assumption based on the error description?

Comment: @GeorgeMarmaridis I'm not sure if I understand your question right, but in this particular project I do have targets with different Swift versions and it seems like Cocoa Pods can't deal with it as is even though Xcode does

Answer (score 5):

I have solved the problem like this:

1. I had two targets: the main project and the tests targets.
2. My main project's target had the 'Use legacy Swift Language version' (in Build Settings) to 'Unspecified (3.0)'.
3. I set the 'Use legacy Swift Language version' to 'No' and it worked fine.

Comment: Where is this option? I don't see it in build settings (xcode 8.3.3)

Comment: Looked for "Swift Language version" in build settings and made sure they were all the same. So this helped me get there

Answer (score 4):

When I opened my `xcodeproj` file it displayed `3.2`, but when I ran `git diff`, I noticed that the `project.pbxproj` had everything as Swift 3.0.

Manually updating the `SWIFT_VERSION` variables to `3.2` with a text editor solved the discrepancy.

I recommend this as a last resort only!

Answer (score 1):

For CocoaPods App v.1.1.1 this problem was solved by setting `Use legacy Swift Language Version` to `Unspecified` in `Build Settings` section for all targets.

Probably it's an app bug - all targets had the same settings but CocoaPods app complaining only about one of them.

**UPD**: to be able to compile project I had to change it back from `Unspecified` to `No`

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem with one target with a difference from 3.0 to 3.0.1

I solved it by manually editing the project file (project.pbxproj) and change 3.0; with 3.0.1;