# pod install error - The following pods are integrated into targets that do not have same Swift version

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm new to IOS development. I have downloaded a source code from the Internet to my Mac machine when I try to run the command "pod install" to install the dependencies library and it throwing me this error message "The following pods are integrated into targets that do not have same Swift version". Currently, I'm running Xcode 8.2.1.

Comment: your pods have different swift version please check read me file of your pod to check the version of swift. might be you need to update your xcode to 9 or 10 depends on which version of swift you are using.

Comment: @ShauketSheikh- How can I identify the appropriate Swift version for the particular project?

Comment: just go to there portal which version they mentioned

Comment: Possible duplicate of [following pods are integrated into targets that do not have the same Swift version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471683/following-pods-are-integrated-into-targets-that-do-not-have-the-same-swift-versi)