# The following pods are integrated into targets that do not have the same Swift version

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I recently had a problem after updating Xcode where I couldn't build the project.

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-code/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/appname.app':
```

I followed the instructions in these answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52452590/4838107
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35316717/4838107

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate
$ sudo gem install cocoapods-clean
$ pod deintegrate
$ pod clean
$ pod install
```

When I try 'pod install' it gives me this:

```
The following pods are integrated into targets that do not have the same Swift version:
Alamofire required by [target] (Swift 3.0)
```

I can't open the project anymore because .xcworkspace is gone so any solution that involves the project open in Xcode won't be any use. I've searched for answers on stackoverflow and this is a problem, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471683/following-pods-are-integrated-into-targets-that-do-not-have-the-same-swift-versi).

Podfile:

```
#Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = 'NO'
            config.build_settings['EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT'] = 'NO'
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0.1'
        end
    end
end
def standard_pods
    pod 'Alamofire'
    ...
end


target '[target]' do
    standard_pods
end
```

Comment: Specify pod version in Podfile that works for the version your app is using

Comment: @AshleyMills I edited my question

Comment: Have you tried pointing to an older version of the Alamofire pod? One that was built for Swift 3?

Comment: I have 13 pods. Will I look up all of them manually or is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: You'll need to do it manually, but it's not a big job. Just check the Releases tab on GitHub. Of course, you'll lose any new features of the pods. Alternatively, update your app to Swift 4. You'll have to do it sooner or later.

Comment: @AshleyMills
I checked GitHub and put this in my Podfile:
`        pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'`
I then tried pod install, pod update etc and I'm still getting the same error: `Alamofire required by [target] (Swift 3.0)`

Comment: @AshleyMills I updated the targets to Swift 4.2 and I was able to successfully install pods. But now it's giving me 'No such module - Alamofire' even though it's right there

Answer (score 0):

In my case i missed to migrate other built targets like unit tests and ui tests :)